# Product Not Found

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am following an instructor, I get an error like this during adding products to the cart of the application he made, when I checked my Service layers and Repo layers, I did not see a problem, could you please share your solution suggestions?

I removed the image upon your warning, the error I got is as follows
**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
"Exception: Product not found!
Services.Abstracts.ProductService.GetOneProduct(int id, bool trackChanges) in ProductService.cs, line 48"**

IProductService layer

```
public interface IProductService
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts(bool trackChanges);
    Product? GetOneProduct(int id,bool trackChanges);
    void CreateProduct(ProductDtoForInsertion productDto);
    void UpdateOneProduct(ProductDtoForUpdate productDto);
    void DeleteOneProduct(int id);
    ProductDtoForUpdate GetOneProductForUpdate(int id, bool trackChanges);
}
```

ProductService Layer

```
public Product? GetOneProduct(int id, bool trackChanges)
{
    var product = _manager.Product.GetOneProduct(id, trackChanges);
    if (product is null)
        throw new Exception("Product not found!");
    return product;
}
```

IProductRepository Layer

```
public interface IProductRepository :IRepositoryBase<Product>
{
    IQueryable<Product> GetAllProducts(bool trackChanges);
    Product? GetOneProduct(int id ,bool  trackChanges);
    void CreateOneProduct(Product product);
    void DeleteOneProduct(Product product);
    void UpdateOneProduct(Product entity);
}
```

ProductRepository Layer

```
public Product? GetOneProduct(int id, bool trackChanges)
{
    return FindByCondition(p=>p.Id.Equals(id),trackChanges);
}
```

Cart.cshtml.cs Layer

```
public IActionResult OnPost(int productId,string returnUrl)
{
    Product ? product =_manager
    .ProductService
    .GetOneProduct(productId,false);

    if (product is not null)
    {
        Cart.AddItem(product,1);
    }
     return Page();
}
```

I tried to write all the layers I use, if there is a layer you think is missing or you want to see, please specify

I reorganized the layers, compared it with the project shared by the tutorial on GitHub, but I couldn't find a solution

I have my repo layers available, I am adding them below

```
public interface IRepositoryBase<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> FindAll(bool trackChanges);
    T? FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, bool trackChanges);
    void Create(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
}

 public T? FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, bool trackChanges)
 {
     return trackChanges
         ? _context.Set<T>().Where(expression).SingleOrDefault()
         :_context.Set<T>().Where(expression).AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault();
 }
```

Comment: please provide more of your repository - especially `FindByCondition`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hello, I tried to edit it, can you take a look again @DanielA.White

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thank you for your warning, I removed the image

Comment: This error is throwed in by your GetOneProduct method, I don't find any error in your code. Have you checked the id you passed into GetOneProduct has the value in database. If the record is not exist in database, then it will throw this error, This is what your code designed for. Or the project do something to handle this error. If it is possible, could you provide the github link of your whole project and the project you refer to? It is more easier to find the solution.

Comment: @XinranShen First of all, thank you for your answer, I found that my error was caused by the layout file, obviously this error occurred because I left an extra space when calling the method name in the section I used for the get method,